# Why is my footer div wrapping everything?

Tags: html, css

Please check this page: http://www.playtrickz.com/basic/basic.html with Firebug. Please tell me why the #pagefooter is wrapping everything. Is it bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a clear property to your footer :

```
#pagefooter {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This works too, in this particular instance. Problems arise if he ever wants to add a floating element next to his footer, however.

Comment: You have some floating blocks in your main_wrapper container.

Comment: ( #figured, #latest { float:left; } )

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer. No extra hacky divs, no presentational class names, just using CSS as it was designed to be used.

Comment: @Alohci The problem with simply clearing the #pagefooter like that, even though perfectly valid, is that you can not have any margin to the floated elements above, and also you can't float anything next to the footer, if you ever would like to. The best solution imho would be to use #pagefooter:before { clear: both } as you could then be able to both float elements next to the footer, and have margin to above floated elements, all in one swoop. However, since IE <=8 does not support the pseudo :before, it's not viable yet.

Comment: @Patrik - All very good points, but you're adding requirements that weren't in the question. That's a very slippery slope, since any additional requirements are unknown, and personally, I would rather stick to the simplest CSS that met the known requirements, and revisit the presentation when the requirements change.

Comment: @Patrik - Also, I'd say that anything that hints of a "clearfix" solution grates horribly with me, since most of the time, there's nothing to "fix" - all that's needed is a proper understanding of how CSS works (or should work, if browser usage could catch up with modern CSS specs). I accept it's not always possible, but where it is, we should be encouraging straightforward CSS usage.

Comment: @Alohci I completely agree with that we should be encouraging proper use and understanding of CSS. And like you said, browsers aren't always up to par with modern CSS standards. And yes, I did suggest a fix for a problem OP hadn't specified, merely because of my own experience with customers who have no knowledge of HTML or CSS, but demand ability to add elements to the code... :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a clearing div after your #main_wrapper

```
<style>
.clear { clear: both; }
</style>
```

Then add: `<div class="clear"></div>` after your #main_wrapper

Comment: Because of your floats. I suggest you read a little about how float's work. But the gist of it is: If you have floated elements and you need to put something absolutely and definitely below those floated elements, you should add a clearing div. If my answer was satisfactory, please click the checkmark. Thx.